# Minimizing a function that depends on two arrays

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Is it possible to minimize a function `fun(x,y)` that depends on two arrays using the Scipy minimizer?

(x and y are two different 1D arrays with different length, e.g. `x=np.array([1,2,3,1,52,5])` and `y=np.array([4,8,9])`)

I'm thinking for something like:

```
minimize(fun, [x,y], method="Powell", tol=1e-3)
```

Is this the correct way to go?

And thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "depends on"?

Comment: Which pairs do you want to pass to the function?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I mean that takes as input x and y

Comment: @tobias if I understood you well: I want both x and y

Comment: Read what `minimize` expects.  If necessary try something close to given examples, and make small steps away from that.

Comment: In other words, does your `fun` conform to `minimize` specs?  `fun(x, *args)`, where `x` is an 1d array of size (n,), `args` is a tuple to just "goes along for the ride", and the value is a scalar?

Comment: @hpaulj Because my function takes values from both arrays respectively (for instance, in the above example the function evaluates first as: `fun(1,4)`, then `fun(2,8)`, then `fun(3,9)`...). So what I want from the minimizer is to optimize both arrays x and y at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that displays the argument that `minimize` supplies, along with its shape:

```
In [300]: def fun(x):
     ...:     print(x, x.shape)
     ...:     return np.sum(x)**2
     ...: 
     ...:
```

Call minimize with a 2d array:

```
In [301]: minimize(fun, np.arange(6).reshape(2,3))
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.] (6,)
[1.49011612e-08 1.00000000e+00 2.00000000e+00 3.00000000e+00
 4.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00] (6,)
[0.         1.00000001 2.         3.         4.         5.        ] (6,)
[0.         1.         2.00000001 3.         4.         5.        ] (6,)
[0.         1.         2.         3.00000001 4.         5.        ] (6,)
[0.         1.         2.         3.         4.00000001 5.        ] (6,)
[0.         1.         2.         3.         4.         5.00000001] (6,)
....
```

Note that the initial `x0` (2,3), has been raveled to a (6,).

I think you take it from there.

Comment: thank you for your answer. From your example of the function `fun(x)`, I guess the minimizer doesn't accept a function that takes as input two arrays. Because what matters for me is my function should take x & y as input. Is there another minimizer that allows this functionality? Otherwise, I will try to edit my function.

Comment: You could use `x0=np.hstack((x,y))` and inside the function split `x` into the two parts.  While `minimize` treats `x` as a 1d array of values, your function does not have to look at it that way.